# Is it possible to create a default implementation for 2 protocol implementations?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I want to know if it is possible to create a default implementation for 2 protocols implementations at the same time.

For example

```swift
protocol Coordinator { 
    var navigationController: UINavigationController
}
protocol Browsing { 
    func openBrowser(url: String)
}
```

And be able to create a default implementation like so

```swift
// This syntax is not correct of course, it is just an example
extension (Coordinator & Browsing) {
     func openBrowser() { 
          //code
          navigationController.present(...)
     }
}
```

I want to be able to do this, because I'll have multiple classes extending both protocols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `where` clause on an extension to require a type conforming to multiple protocols.

Either of these will work and do the same thing. It's up to you which one makes sense. I'd probably go with the second one since the method came from `Browsing` and this adds the implementation when it also conforms to `Coordinator`.

```
extension Coordinator where Self: Browsing {
     func openBrowser() { 
          //code
     }
}
```

```
extension Browsing where Self: Coordinator {
     func openBrowser() { 
          //code
     }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! I knew I was close, it's like using `where Item:` or `where Element:` but didn't know it was Self.